# Will this pair be moved?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, std-pair

Under the C++11 standard, is the following pair guaranteed to be moved into the function?

```
//objects available: key, value
//corresponding type available: pairtype
//function available: void foo(pairtype pair); copies the pair by default

foo({std::move(key),std::move(value)}); //pair moved?
```

or do I have to do the move myself?

```
foo(std::move(pairtype(std::move(key),std::move(value))); //needed?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Initializer lists are not expressions, so they do not have a type and they do not yield a value. This means that the following:

```
{std::move(key),std::move(value)}
```

Does not *in itself* create a pair. Initializer lists are just a syntactic construct used for initialization, and in this case the function parameter will be constructed by **directly** invoking the constructor of `pairtype` with `std::move(key)` and `std::move(value)` as arguments.

There is no creation of temporaries involved - the only thing to be aware of is that `explicit` constructors will not be considered when performing list-initialization (for instance, this would not work with an instance of `std::tuple<>`).

Which means that the invocation of `foo` we just discussed, i.e.:

```
foo({std::move(key),std::move(value)}
```

Is technically different from this invocation:

```
foo(std::move(pairtype(std::move(key),std::move(value)))
```

Here, you are intentionally creating a temporary and moving it into the function parameter (the compiler may then elide this move per 12.8/31, but this is another story).

Notice, that the call to `std::move()` here is superfluous, since temporaries are rvalues. The function parameter will be move-constructed from the temporary object anyway. You can therefore write:

```
foo(pairtype(std::move(key),std::move(value)))
```

Notice, that `pairtype` will be an instance of the `std::pair<>` class template, which means you will have to specify template arguments manually. To avoid this, you can use `std::make_pair()`:

```
foo(std::make_pair(std::move(key),std::move(value)))
```

Comment: I thought that explicit constructors were only not considered with list copy-initalization, and that is going to be fixed in C++14

Comment: @TemplateRex: Not sure about C++14, but in C++11 passing an argument to a function is a copy-initialization context (see 8.5/15 and 8.5.4/1). Since here we are list-initializing, this is a copy-list-initialization (see 8.5.4/1), and what applies are 8.5.4/3 (4th bullet) and 13.3.1.7/1.

Comment: ah yes, I read the Q too quickly. So does the same apply to `emplace` like functions (taking rvalue references)? Can they also not call explicit constructors?

Comment: @TemplateRex: If I understand the question correctly, I think they can. `emplace` functions just call the constructor directly and perfect-forward the arguments they receive, so it is not a copy-initialization context, but a direct-initialization one.